# Group action and determine number of orbits and their size.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

The group $ (S_5 ; ∘) $ has action on a set $ M $. $M$ is the set off all two-element subset of the set {$1,2,3,4,5$}. The action is given by {$x,y$}${^φ}$$=$ {$xφ,yφ$}.

Determine the number of orbits and find out their size.

I do not have any idea how to start, I am quite confused about group actions, their orbits, etc. So I will appreciate any help with this exercise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**

Choose any two elements of $M$. Is there an element of $S_{5}$ that takes the first to the second?

**Alternative Hint**

Given $\{1, 2\} \in M$, and an arbitrary element of $M$, is there an element of $S_{5}$ that takes the first to the second?

Comment: Yes, of course for example {$1,2$} and {$3,4$} and permutation $(1 3)(2 4)(5)$  /as cycle/ gives {$1,2$} to {$3,4$}. So now I know that this mapping is action, but there are 25 permutation and 15 two-elements subset. How to continue with orbits and their size. Probably Burnside lema can be useful for this problem.

Comment: It's easier than that. The hint is that there is only one orbit.

Comment: Any arbitrary element of M can be "transform" by suitable permutation to any previously given element from the set M. It means that each element of the set M, has the same orbit, so the orbit is only one. And what I think is that the orbit is whole set M, it means that the size of orbit is 15. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes. (And thanks.)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and time, it was very beneficial for me that you did not say me whole solution but tried to direct me to the solution.